# How to maintain car battery if I'm not going to use it for a while?

Tags: battery-drain

I own the Honda Accord 2019 model. I'll be traveling for a month, and won't be using the car. The car batteries may go dead because of this.

I read that I can use a trickle charger for such a situation. But the problem is that I live in an apartment complex, and I won't have access to an AC source to plug the trickle charger into. And as I park the car outside, I don't want to keep my hood open as well, assuming I have an AC power source.

So is there any other way I can ensure that my batteries don't go dead?

Comment: Can you take the battery off the car and keep it inside, occasionally trickle charging it?

Comment: @HandyHowie thank you for the suggestion. But from the looks of it, this model is heavily reliant on the battery I believe. If removing the battery, then it may mess with the other stuff in the car?

Answer (score 2):

I've had great results with the brand known as Battery Tender, primarily because they are not trickle chargers, which "push" electricity into a battery regardless of state of charge. Battery Tender makes maintainers, smart devices which regulate the level of power being applied.

I was pleased to discover, for your purposes that you can get a Battery Tender solar maintainer! [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004Q83TGO) is one source for such a product and any good search should result in other options. Watch out that you don't get a trickle charger, but you'll find other brands available.

[image: solar battery tender]